# Custom Icon in SearchView Android

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, searchview

I have the `Ham Burger Navigation Drawer Icon`, `App Name` and `Search Icon` in the `ToolBar`. This is my small part of `HomeScreen`.
[image]

When I click `Search Icon`, the `SearchView` is shown as follows: 
[image]

There is an `Back Icon` of `Navigation Drawer`. I want to disable/hide it, and add the custom one here.

My `SearchView` has following properties:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_search_places"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

I am working on `Fragment`. What can be done here, so that I disable/ hide the back icon and include the custom one ?

**Edit:**

I am able to customize the icon from changing my `styles.xml` file, where
I include this:

```
<resources>
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Now, How can I handle the disable/hide the back icon?

I tried this but I am unable to find the solution.

```
((ToolbarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
((ToolbarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Fragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);    
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchViewMenuItem.getActionView();
    int searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
    ImageView v = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_new_icon); 
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: I am unable to hide that `back icon`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set drawable to the homeAsUp button programmatically -

```
ActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

For support actionbar -

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

To hide up button -

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Before adding new, I need to hide or disable first.

Comment: you can use - drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

Comment: i've edited my answer. Are you using actionbar or toolbar ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not for the custom one.

But, I apply the method `MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {...}` to handle the `click event` of the `back icon` and do my stuff on `onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {...}` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search_places);
    searchItem.setIcon(FontIconDrawable.inflate(getContext(), R.xml.ic_search));
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                // my stuff are here
           return true;
        }
    });
}
```